# phonegap barcodescanner: how to multiple scan at a time

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, barcode-scanner

I am developing a sencha touch application with phonegap and targetting for android devices. In the app, there is a option to scan a barcode. I have used [this link](https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/261) to implement barcode scan. Here, user can scan a barcode and come back to the sencha screen.

As per my requirement, the app should allow users to scan more than one barcodes at a time and it should come back to screen when the user is done with scan. I am expecting similar approach that phonegap capture plugin is used (allows user to take multiple images / videos / sound at the same time and result will be in an array).

Is there way to do this multiple scan at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

I just faced the same problem, and here is a workaround that i came up with.

In a nutshell: whenever a code is successfully returned, i save the scanned information into a array, and immediately restart the scanning.

This is the code i use to test my workaround inside a simple meteor app:

```
  // list to collect successfully scans
  var scanned_list=[];

  // callback function that will be executed everytime barcodescanner.scan ends without error
  scannedOneItem = function (result) {

    // user cancelled the scan: now check if we have something scanned already or not:
    if(result.cancelled){
      if(scanned_list.length>0){
        // no items scanned, user cancelled
        alert("Scanned items: " + scanned_list.length);
      }
      else{
        alert("Scanned canceled");
      }
    }
    // a item was scanned successfully - add it to list, and restart barcodescanner
    else{
      scanned_list.append(result.text);
      cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
          scannedOneItem,
          function (error) {
            alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
          }
      );
    }
  }
  Template.barcode_scanner.events({
    'click button': function () {
      // start scanning when button is pressed:
      cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
          scannedOneItem,
          function (error) {
            alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
          }
      );
    }
  });
```

Comment: This doesn't work. The scanner never restarts, it just closes after scanning one item. I copied and tested the exact same code in this answer.

Comment: i dont have any project to test this on right now. did you do any debugging on it why it failed for you ? the first scan is successful ? does it than give you a error from the barcode-scanner ? if the first scan is successful, it should definitive try to open the barcode-scanner again. if it doesnt do that it looks like something changed in the barcode-scanner....

Answer (score 1):

The plugin does not currently support this functionality. You will have to either contact the author of the plugin to make modifications or do it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

It has worked using @80prozet solution above, you have to consider canceling the scan using the native back button:

```
async scan_products (){
    const results           = await this.barcode.scan();

    if(results.cancelled) {
        this.platform.ready().then(() => {
            // catch the native back button to cancel scan
            this.platform.registerBackButtonAction(function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                event.stopPropagation();

                console.log("Scanned Canceled");
            });
        });
    }
    // a item was scanned successfully - add it to list, and restart barcodescanner //
    else{
        this.scanned_products.push(results.text);
        this.scan_products();
    }


    console.log(results);
}
```